# If A causes B & A causes C, can B modify the effect of A on C?

Tags: interaction, causality, mediation, confounding

Suppose I roll out an initiative to promote a new vaccine in a country, call this intervention A. A causes uptake of vaccines C, but it may or may not also cause backlash from community leaders towards the initiative B.

Suppose the backlash B reduces uptake of vaccines C, but only in the presence of the intervention A.

In such a situation, is it better to say B is a mediator on the pathway from A to C or an effect modifier of the effect of A on C? In general, if you have

A -> B
  > C

is it then also possible for B to modify A->C ?

Answer (score 2):

it is a classical Mediation Problem in which the  effect from A to B and the effect from B to C are of opposite direction. This can lead to the main effect (A to C) not being detectable when solely running a regression analysis C~A.

Because the supposed effect of A on C is "counteracted" by the mediation effect of B. In these scenarios a mediation analysis can "unmask" such combination of effects.

Sidenote: Some professors and websites promote the idea that one of the conditions for running a mediation is that the main effect A->C must be significant. However in cases such as the one you described the main effect can be not significant because their is a mediation. That is why this condition is false.

The answer you are looking for is that B is a mediator of the effect A-> C

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I am wondering, is in such a situation does it make sense to call B a mediator, if B cannot exist in the absence of A? In the example, I have given, "backlash against intervention A" is only defined for the scenario where A is rolled out. In the absence of A, this construct does not make sense. So can you still call B a mediator then?

Comment: That is a good question. From a statistical point of view, I would argue it is still a mediator as it mediates the effect of A on C. Given that A is zero thus no intervention took place then B would be zero as well ( as you would multiply zero with the regression coefficient between A and B. And the effect of B on C would also be zero as well for the same reason. In your described scenario A would predict B with no residuals. From a methodological point of view I am not sure